# React how to clone props

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm learning

I have problem with this function in my component:

```
...
export default function Main(props) {
...
...
...
const deleteMessage = (index) => {
        let test = props.data.contacts;
        // let test2 = { ...props.data.contacts}; Also tried with this
        test[currentContact].messages.splice(index, 1);
        // props.setData({ ...props.data, test }) this is commented and should't be executed
    }
return (...<JSX Elements>...)
}
```

When I run `<li onCLick={() => deleteMessage(index)}> Delete this message </li>` the change is performed on the parent component's status.

Although props.setData () is commented out in this sample code, props.data is still affected by this function's changes.

How can I clone props.data in a new object and work only on this, without chaging props.data?

Comment: let test = { ...props.data.contacts} should work fine if its an object, if you use the spread operator then you create a clone of it so it won't effect the original state.

Comment: add the structure your state to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating the state make sure that every part of the nested structure until you reach the actual thing that you want to update gets cloned.

```
test[currentContact].messages.splice(index, 1);
```

This is bad because `splice` modifies the `messages` array.

Infact `test[currentContact].messages` itself is bad because `test[currentContact]` is being mutated.

```
// let test2 = { ...props.data.contacts}; Also tried with this
```

Object and Array spread syntaxes can be used to clone and prevent mutation, but here too make sure that `props.data` gets cloned first and then `contacts`.

---

Examples of updating arrays and objects immutably:

```js
const bla = {
  foo: {
    bar: [1]
  }
}

// here's how you can update `bla` immutably if you want to add an element to the nested array
const clonedBla = { ...bla,
  foo: {
    ...bla.foo,
    bar: [...bla.foo.bar, 2]
  }
}
console.log(bla, clonedBla)
```

```js
const bla = {
  foo: [{
      a: "a",
    },
    {
      b: "b",
      arr: [1, 2],
    },
  ],
};

// if we want to remove the second element of `bla.foo[1].arr`
const updatedBla = {
  ...bla,
  foo: bla.foo.map((el, index) =>
    index === 1 ?
    {
      ...el,
      arr: el.arr.filter((_, iIndex) => iIndex !== 1),
    } :
    el
  ),
};
console.log(updatedBla)
```

Comment: Yes! This is it, I've cloned just the array of the messages like this:  'let messages = [...props.data.contacts[currentContact].messages];' And now manipulating this don't change the main status! Thank You! It is strange how this works, but I'm gona improve more.

Comment: @GianlucaNapoletano I've added examples to the answer.

Comment: Thank You! I have never been in the situation of manipulating cloned arrays of objects, without modifying the original one before starting to study react js. Can you recommend to me a guide that explains why it works like this?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning is the right approach, we usually want to avoid mutating  arrays / objects directly.

I think the most common modern way to clone either an array or an object is by spreading it's contents into a new variable via the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Example -

```js
const originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const originalObject = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
};

const newArray = [...originalArray, 5, 6];
const newObject = {
  ...originalObject,
  'e': 5,
  'f': 6,
};

console.log(newArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(newObject); // {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

As you can see, it acts as a member in the array / object, and essentially spreads the original variable while creating a new one instead of being a reference to the original.